# Ubuntu 11.10 Loading into TTY Mode

Tags: tty, mode

I'm sure that this has been asked before. I'm not completely new to Ubuntu, I started with 9.04, but I stopped using it for a long time, and am currently Dual-Booting 11.10 alongside Windows 7 on my laptop.

I wanted to enable the Compiz effects, but Ubuntu was not recognizing my graphics card (nVidia GeForce 525M) so I thought maybe updating the driver would help. I Ctrl+Alt+F1 entered TTY mode, and I did the following:

```
sudo service lightdm stop
cd ~/Downloads
sudo sh ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-290.10.run
```

and then I went through the setup for the nVidia driver. It said it installed correctly, so I restarted my laptop through Ctrl+Alt+Delete, and then when I went to load Ubuntu, it loaded in TTY mode.

I can't seem to figure out how to get back to the User Interface for Ubuntu.

Anyone who could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Log in as your user, then try running `sudo nvida-xconfig` . Then `sudo service lightdm start`

Comment: Doing that brought up this screen [link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=23upfyf&s=5) Which coincidentally is the screen that Ubuntu actually loads to when I choose it at the boot manager. Sorry if that is misleading from my original post

Comment: Bad news - According to the Nvidia Linux Forums, there is no support for your card in Linux. http://nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=161471 I did not find any solution and I can not test your hardware. If the nouveau driver (the default driver) does not work you can file a bug against it in Launchpad. You can try filing a bug report with Nvidia as well.

Comment: Oh, great. That sucks. I'll just have to reinstall Ubuntu to fix my TTY issue then. Thanks for checking that. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me and I had to reinstall Ubuntu :( I don't know why it does it but I think the only thing you can do is reinstall. However someone correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: I installed Ubuntu through Windows 7 using Wubi just as a precursor, because I had a feeling something would happen lol. I did it mostly for last resort. I will wait and see if anyone else has a way to fix it, and then leave unistall/reinstall to the end. Did you also have issues with the wireless not working? Mine fails to turn on, when I go into the settings, I turn wireless on, and it immediately turns itself off. I can connect through Wicd, but I cannot install any software, because Ubuntu thinks I'm not online.

Comment: I did the exact same thing and installed through Windows 7 and I do have wireless problems but only after I wake my computer up from sleeping.

Comment: I've had wireless problems since I installed it. The only way to install any programs is to go wired.

Comment: if reinstalling fixed it then mark my answer as the right one that way people know it's what they have to do.